# Find binary sequence in NumPy binary array

Tags: python, search, numpy

As part of creating a software defined receiver and decoder, I want to find sync pulses in weather satellite data.  The data is first digitized to a 0-1 array.

The code below is working. The convolution method is sufficiently fast. The slow method is not.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient or "Pythonic" way to do it.

```
def findPulseSlow(data, pulse):
    # find indexes of occurrences of pulse in data
    # data and pulse are numpy arrays of 0-1 elements
    # tolerate up to 3 incorrect values
    # takes 2 minutes per Mb on AMD FX8150
    maxerr=3
    return np.fromiter( \
        ( i for i in range(0,len(data)-len(pulse)) \
            if sum(np.logical_xor(data[i:(i+len(pulse))], pulse))<=maxerr ),\
        np.int)

def findPulseConvolve2(data,pulse):
    maxerr=3
    required = len(pulse)-maxerr
    doubleConvolution = np.convolve(data,pulse[::-1])+\
                        np.convolve(1-data,1-pulse[::-1])
    return 1-len(pulse)+np.where(doubleConvolution>=required)[0]
```

Here is a complete test framework:

testPulse.py

```
import numpy as np

NOAAsyncA=np.concatenate( ([4*[0],7*[1,1,0,0],8*[0]]) )

def getFixedTestData():
    data = np.zeros(1000)
    syncL = len(NOAAsyncA)
    data[12:(12+syncL)]=NOAAsyncA
    data[257:(257+syncL)]=NOAAsyncA
    data[900:(900+syncL)]=NOAAsyncA
    return ([12,257,900], data)

def getRandomTestData():
    # create random 1 Megabit data, insert 10 NOAA sync pulses in data
    # return correct pulse start locations, data
    global NOAAsyncA
    data = np.random.randint(2, size=1000000)
    # make an ascending list of random spots to insert the pulse
    insertAidx = np.sort(np.random.randint(1000000, size=10))
    # insert the pulses
    for l in insertAidx:
        data[l:(l+len(NOAAsyncA))]=NOAAsyncA
    # return the pulse locations and the data
    return (insertAidx, data)

def findPulseSlow(data, pulse):
    # find indexes of occurrences of pulse in data
    # data and pulse are numpy arrays of 0-1 elements
    # tolerate up to 3 incorrect values
    # takes 2 minutes per Mb on AMD FX8150
    maxerr=3
    return np.fromiter( \
        ( i for i in range(0,len(data)-len(pulse)) \
            if sum(np.logical_xor(data[i:(i+len(pulse))], pulse))<=maxerr ),\
        np.int)

def findPulseConvolve1(data, pulse):
    # tests for locations of 1's only. Bad idea.  
    # max error count
    maxerr=0
    required = sum(pulse)-maxerr
    return 1-len(pulse)+np.where(np.convolve(data,pulse[::-1])>=required)[0]

def findPulseConvolve2(data,pulse):
    maxerr=3
    required = len(pulse)-maxerr
    doubleConvolution = np.convolve(data,pulse[::-1])+\
                        np.convolve(1-data,1-pulse[::-1])
    return 1-len(pulse)+np.where(doubleConvolution>=required)[0]

def Test(name,generator,finder):
    global NOAAsyncA
    (correctLocations, data) = generator()
    syncAidx = finder(data, NOAAsyncA)
    passedTest = False
    if len(syncAidx)==len(correctLocations):
        if (syncAidx==correctLocations).all():
            passedTest = True
    print "Test: "+name
    print "Test Result: "+str(passedTest)
    print "found syncA at: "+str(syncAidx)
    print "should be at: "+str(correctLocations)
    return passedTest


Test("fixed findPulseConvolve1", getFixedTestData, findPulseConvolve1)
Test("fixed findPulseConvolve2", getFixedTestData, findPulseConvolve2)
Test("random findPulseConvolve1", getRandomTestData, findPulseConvolve1)
Test("random findPulseConvolve2", getRandomTestData, findPulseConvolve2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I get to your specific question, here are some general comments:

1. Since you are working with binary data, you should tell NumPy that your `dtype` is `bool` everywhere that you can.  That will lower memory requirements and speed up certain operations.  For example, `data = np.zeros(1000)` in `getFixedTestData()` should become `data = np.zeros(1000, dtype=bool)`.  The default NumPy `dtype` is `float` which is not what you want.
2. The python convention for naming functions is `snake_case` i.e. all lowercase with underscores, not `camelCase`.  So `findPulseSlow` should be `find_pulse_slow` etc.
3. The right approach for optimizing your currently too-slow function is to use line profiling.  I really like the [`line_profiler` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/).  If you use IPython you can [use it very easily as an inline magic function](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html).
4. Doing #3 will mean unpacking that formidable iterator comprehension you wrote!  Instead of squeezing it all on one line, I'd define a generator function for the iterator, and try to be extremely explicit so that every line has only one function call, like this:

---

```
def yield_convolve(arr_1, arr_2):
    """Yields indices of arr_1 where arr_2 nearly matches."""
    MAX_ERR = 3
    len_1, len_2 = len(arr_1), len(arr_2)  # I assume arr_2 is always shorter than arr_1
    min_matches = len_2 - MAX_ERR
    num_windows = len_1 - len_2
    for idx in xrange(num_windows):
        arr_1_window = arr_1[idx:(idx+len_2)]
        summand = np.equal(arr_1_window, arr_2)
        sum_ = np.count_nonzero(summand)
        condition = sum_ >= min_matches
        if condition:
            yield idx    



def find_pulse_slow_revised(arr_1, arr_2):
    return np.fromiter(yield_convolve(arr_1, arr_2), dtype=int)
```

---

I was probably overly expressive in the function I made -- it could be cleaned up by avoiding assigment to so many temporary variables but when doing line profiling this style really helps isolate the slow steps.

5. **Watch out for places where you are inadvertently causing interconversion of NumPy data types and native Python data types.**  For example, `sum(np.logical_xor(...)` should be `np.sum(np.logical_xor(...)`
6. I thought the `np.logical_xor` part you did was clever, but to my eyes at least it was a bit easier to grok using `len(pulse) - maxerr` as a criterion and using `np.equal` instead of `np.logical_xor`, so that is what I did in my example above.
7. I did a few timing tests with my revised function and it was at least ~20-30x faster than your `findPulseSlow()`.  Using `np.sum` instead of `sum` was responsible for most of the speedup.  Using `np.count_nonzero` instead of `np.sum` gave an additional 2× or so.  Here's an example of some code from my IPython notebook, along with some output from the line profiler.

---

```
_, fixed_dat = getFixedTestData()

%timeit findPulseSlow(fixed_dat, NOAAsyncA)

%timeit find_pulse_slow_revised(fixed_dat, NOAAsyncA)

%lprun -f find_pulse_slow_revised -f yield_convolve find_pulse_slow_revised(fixed_dat, NOAAsyncA)


10 loops, best of 3: 54 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
```

---

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.004039 s
File: <ipython-input-95-5e22e2fbabc9>
Function: yield_convolve at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def yield_convolve(arr_1, arr_2):
     2                                               """Yields indices of arr_1 where arr_2 nearly matches."""
     3         1            1      1.0      0.0      MAX_ERR = 3
     4         1            1      1.0      0.0      len_1, len_2 = len(arr_1), len(arr_2)  # I assume arr_2 is always shorter than arr_1
     5         1            0      0.0      0.0      min_matches = len_2 - MAX_ERR
     6         1            0      0.0      0.0      num_windows = len_1 - len_2
     7       961          407      0.4     10.1      for idx in xrange(num_windows):
     8       960          579      0.6     14.3          arr_1_window = arr_1[idx:(idx+len_2)]
     9       960         1511      1.6     37.4          summand = np.equal(arr_1_window, arr_2)
    10       960          642      0.7     15.9          sum_ = np.count_nonzero(summand)
    11       960          476      0.5     11.8          condition = sum_ >= min_matches
    12       960          422      0.4     10.4          if condition:
    13         3            0      0.0      0.0              yield idx       

Total time: 0.006642 s
File: <ipython-input-95-5e22e2fbabc9>
Function: find_pulse_slow_revised at line 15

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    15                                           def find_pulse_slow_revised(arr_1, arr_2):
    16         1         6642   6642.0    100.0      return np.fromiter(yield_convolve(arr_1, arr_2), dtype=int)
```

---

8. Using the built-in `np.convolve` solution is definitely the way to go and is still way faster than even the improved "slow" method.